# Distribution of $0$-$1$ matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, probability-distributions, asymptotics, determinants

Consider $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\{0,1\}$. The determinants of these ranges from $0$ to the Hadamard bound $\frac{(n+1)^{\frac{n+1}2}}{2^n}$. Assume $n$ is large enough.

**What does the distribution of the determinants look like? Is it normal or skewed?**

**What proportion of such $n\times n$ determinants is singular?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much is known about these Hadamard matrices, this [talk](http://mypage.iu.edu/~worrick/slides/SpectrumANU.pdf) by William Orrick gives a good overview:

The first few moments of the determinant $\det M$ are known exactly, for large $n$ the distribution of $|\det M|$ is conjectured to be log-normal.

For the number of singular matrices, see [OEIS.](http://oeis.org/A046747) The large-$n$ limit of the probability that a $n\times n$ matrix is singular is conjectured to be $n^2/2^n$.

Comment: The poster is talking about binary matrices, with entries from 0,1. There is a transformation that carries them to matrices with 1,-1, some of which are Hadamard.  Also, I would say much is unknown, and that Orrick's talk is close to state of the art at present. Gerhard "Prefers The Phrase 'Binary Matrices'" Paseman, 2017.06.02.

Comment: Standard usage is \det M rather than {\rm det}\,M. If you write a\det b or a\det(b) you see $a\det b$ or $a\det(b)$ respectively, and I include both examples so that you can see the context-dependent nature of the spacing.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_n$ be a random matrix where each entry is either $1$ or $-1$, and $B_n$ be a random matrix where each entry is either $0$ or $1$.  The distributions of the determinants of these two matrices are closely related.

Indeed, since the distribution of $A_n$ is symmetric around $0$, we can WLOG assume that the first row and column of our $A_n$ are entirely equal to $1$.  Subtract the first row from each other row, and we're left with a lower right  $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix where each entry is either $0$ or $-2$.  Pulling out a factor of $-2$ from each row (and again using the fact that the distribution is symmetric around $0$), we see that the determinant of $A_n$ has the same distribution as $2^{n-1}$ times the determinant of $B_{n-1}$.

The distribution of the determinant of $A_n$ is log-normal.  This was originally stated by [Girko in 1997](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0040585X97975939), but Girko's proof is opaque and seems to skirt some technical details.  More transparent proofs were later given by [Nguyen and Vu](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0752), and by [Bao, Pan, and Zhou](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5823).

Comment: I appreciate you nice input.